# Server error in reports application

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2005, reporting

I have a server with SQL Server 2005 installed with the latest service packs. SQL Server 2012 express was been installed on same machine and seems to have broken the Reporting services service. When I browse to localhost/reports, I get the unhandled exception

> 'The ReportServerVirtualDirectory' element is not a configuration file element.

Pretty sure this it to do with the corresponding service being stopped. But it wont start up anymore. The express one is started, but the older 2005 won't start manually (even if I stop the express one), and if I try starting the service in reporting services configuration, it gets a timeout message. I've tried repairing the old installation reporting services but it hasn't helped.